# How to test if a td is a child of a tr in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to void treating the last tr's tds of a table while iteration through all **td**'s in a table's columns:

```
for (i = 0; i < tableLength; i++) {
  $('#myTable>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(' + i + ')').each(function() {
      //stuf to do : if $(this)... not a child of $('#myTable tr:last') 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Put the code in the question, not in a comment please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the `<td>` is in the last `<tr>` using the following:

```
$(this).parent().is(':last-child')
```

For example:

```js
$('table tr td').each(function() {  
 if( $(this).parent().is(':last-child') )
  {
  
  }
  else
  {
   $(this).css('background', 'red');
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```